# Date in varchar format not working with query with date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field name 'orderdate' (type Date format yyyy-mm-dd).when i am executing the following query it doesnot show any result.What may be the problem, is the date format used in my query creating problem.plz soggest any solution .I can not change the format of orderdate in table. my query is

```
SELECT
    stationerytype,
    txntype,
    stationeryqtyrecd,
    stationeryqtyissued,
    stationeryissueddate,
    orderdate,
    SUM(stationeryqtyrecd) as ttlreceived  
FROM tblstationerystock 
WHERE
    (
        stationerytype ='A4 White Ream' AND
        txntype ='received'
    ) AND orderdate<07/09/21
```

Comment: You'll need to convert the values to dates before you can do an accurate comparison. Doing a string comparison on a date in that format won't produce the results you want.

Comment: In `AND orderdate<07/09/21` the expression which you want to be distinguished as data is really treated as arithmetic expression `07/09/21=0.03703704`.

Comment: @Akina how can i overcome this plz suggest.

Comment: ?? The answer with the solution is already provided...

Answer (score 0):

Simply enclose your `date` in a Single `'` quote or Double `"` qoute like `orderdate<'2021-07-09';` and kindly try using the default MySQL Date Format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

```
SELECT  stationerytype,
txntype,
stationeryqtyrecd,
stationeryqtyissued,
stationeryissueddate,
orderdate,SUM(stationeryqtyrecd) as ttlreceived  
FROM tblstationerystock 
WHERE (stationerytype ='A4 White Ream' AND  txntype ='received') AND orderdate<'2021-07-09';
```

> MySQL DATE is one of  the five temporal data types used for managing date values. MySQL uses yyyy-mm-dd format for storing a date value. This format is fixed and it is not possible to change it.

> For example, you may prefer to use mm-dd-yyyy format but you can’t. Instead, you follow the standard date format and use the DATE_FORMAT function to format the date the way you want.

Check [this](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date/).